# dask read_sql error when querying from MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, sqlalchemy, dask

I am using python 2.7 with dask and trying to query a db table from a remote machine to a dask dataframe

I have a multiple column index in the table, and I try to read it using the following script

```
ddf = dd.read_sql_table("table name", "mysql://user:pass@ip:port/Dbname",spesific column name).head()
```

And getting the following error

> ```
> start = asanyarray(start) * 1.0 TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32')
> ```
>
> dtype('S32') dtype('S32')

I got the sqlalchemy uri as explained [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html)

i'm not sure what's the problem, when I try to query by another column as the index, and only use the ddf head(), i don't get an error, and when I try to compute the whole ddf i get the same error, i assume it's an issue regarding the column not being of unique values, I don't have a single column index, but multiple column, what is the solution to read the entire table here?

Thanks.

full traceback

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "path", line 28, in <module>
>     ddf = dd.read_sql_table("tablename", "mysql://user:pass@ip:port/dbname","indexcolumn")   File "file", line
> 123, in read_sql_table
>     divisions = np.linspace(mini, maxi, npartitions + 1).tolist()   File
> "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py",
> line 108, in linspace
>     start = asanyarray(start) * 1.0 TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32')
> dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

Comment: Can you verify that the equivalent pandas operation works?

Comment: Please show a more detailed traceback and perhaps run debug to find the value of `start` when the error happens.

Comment: @MRocklin works great with pandas

Comment: @mdurant the value of start is {str}'-1000001542'

Comment: Looks like you see a string that ought to be a number

Comment: Please explain what you suspect the issue to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case where you provide no further information or only specify number of partitions, the partitioning logic in `read_sql_table` only works for numbers, because we need a way to make ordered divisions between the minimum and maximum values.

Apparently, but the query (to get the max/min) is returning a string for this case. `read_sql_table` can still work, but you will need to define the divisions to split on yourself, and supply them with the divisions keyword, e.g.,

```
ddf = dd.read_sql_table("table name", "mysql://user:pass@ip:port/Dbname", 
    'index_col', divisions=['aardvark', 'llama', 'tapir', 'zebra']).head()
```

Alternatively, the string in question certainly looks like a number, so you might need to update the schema of the table to make sure it is interpreted as a number.

Comment: Could you provide a full example of the first solution?

Comment: could you provide with a working example for the first solution?

Comment: thanks! so, just for me to understand it all the way, the divisions  are in terms of the index column and the index column only? (and how will it use them, given that you need to sort the strings to fit within those divisions, does it use lexicographic order?

Comment: Yes, the divisions are the boundaries of each partition for the index column, say the second partition would be `WHERE index_col > "llama" AND index_col <= "tapir"`. If you provide divisions, it is up to you to order them, and understand what your DB will understand by it.